# Why is this error coming?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, tuples

I have the following code and I am using the c++11 tuple in the standard template library.

```
    #include <tuple>
#include <cstdio> 
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>  
#include <string> 
using namespace std ; 
vector<tuple<string,string,string,string,string,string> > lst ; 
    int main()
    {
        string t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6 ; 
        cin>>t1>>t2>>t3>>t4>>t5>>t6 ;
        char c ; 
        tuple<string,string,string,string,string,string> tup = make_tuple(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6); 
        while(!feof(stdin))
        {
            list.push_back(tup) ;
            cin>>t1 ; 
            cin>>t2 ; 
            cin>>t3 ; 
            cin>>t4 ; 
            cin>>t5 ; 
            cin>>t6 ;   
            tup = make_tuple(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6) ;
            getchar_unlocked() ; 
            getchar_unlocked() ;
        }
        sort(list.begin(), list.end(), mySort) ; 
        print() ; 
    }
```

It's showing the error

```
Expected primary expression before '>' token. on the line `tuple<string,string,string,string,string,string> tup = make_tuple(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6);`
```

Can anybody tell me why is this compiler error coming.

Comment: Did you include the `<tuple>` header?

Comment: This is either not the complete code or you posted something else.

Comment: Yes, I have included all the necessary headers including <tuple>

Comment: It is the complete code, except the print() function and the global vector list

Comment: @ps06756: please add headers and unsing namespace declaration if you have one

Comment: Seems like a `class` with named data may be more appropriate than `tupple` here.

Comment: @crashmstr I can't understand what you intend to say.

Comment: did you enable `-std=c++11` ?

Comment: @ps06756 6 nameless fields in a `tuple` vs. a `class` with named data. A `class` *may* be more clear in design and use than a generic nameless `tuple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you included all headers and have all functions defined, a high chance is that you missed to enable C++11 flag

You need to compile using `-std=c++11` flag

Comment: Where does the error suggest that?

Comment: @interjay sorry when I see something `...primary expression before '>' ` I assume it likely to be `-std=C++11`, because of `> >` usage in nested templates thing. Agreed it was a blind guess

Comment: Strange, I would assume that lack of c++11 would cause an error earlier, e.g. in `#include <tuple>`. But OP seems to confirm that this helped.